# Find all .sql-Files in a Directory and execute them with sqlcmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line, sqlcmd

I'm still a CMD beginner and would like to import all SQL files I have in a directory structure with sqlcmd to my DB.

If I copy all *.sql into the root folder the following command works:

```
@ECHO ON
FOR %%G in (*.sql) DO sqlcmd /S *SERVER* /d *DB* /U *USER* /P *PW* -i"%%G" > LOG_lastrun.txt 2> LOG_errors.txt

pause
```

```
@ECHO ON
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=sql" %%G in (*.sql) DO sqlcmd /S *SERVER* /d *DB* /U *USER* /P *PW* -i"%%G" > LOG_lastrun.txt 2> LOG_errors.txt

pause
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me FOR /F loops. Can you help me here?

Comment: Show us the command (that you tried) that *does not* work.

Comment: ```@ECHO ON
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=sql" %%G in (*.sql) DO sqlcmd /S *SERVER* /d *DB* /U *USER* /P *PW* -i"%%G" > LOG_lastrun.txt 2> LOG_errors.txt
pause```

Comment: What's wrong with `for` (without `/F`)? what do you want `for /F` for? or do you actually need `for /R`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FOR /F` works differently. It runs a command. Jusr `*.sql` is not a command. Also, I suspect that you want to concatenate stdout and stderr output using `>>`.

```
@ECHO ON
SET "SERVER_NAME=*SERVER*"
SET "DB_NAME=*DB*"
SET "LOGIN_ID=*USER*"
SET "PASS=*PW*"

FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('DIR /B "*.sql"') DO (
    sqlcmd  -S %SERVER_NAME% -d %DB_NAME% -U %LOGIN_ID% -P %PASS% -i "%%~G" >> LOG_lastrun.txt 2>> LOG_errors.txt
)

pause
```

Comment: I had to add IN ('DIR /S /B "*.sql"') - works perfect now and i think i understood ;-) many thanks!